# Copy files to site-packages

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I want to copy some files to the `site-packages` folder.

How to define in `setup.py` to copy files to the `site-packes` folder instead of a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

The site-packages directories is supposed to contain modules (e.g. spam.py) or packages (spam/__init__.py).  In a setup script, the things referenced in py_modules and packages will get installed in site-packages.  Could you explain what it is you want to do that does not work with py_modules or packages?